# group replacement in php

Tags: php, regex

i need to modify links (globally) in this way

http://www.domain.de/specific-folder/{data}/#link

to this:

`http://{data}.domain.de/#link`

`{data} = changing folder name`

I tried it, but i can't figure out how to handle group replacement in php (preg_replace)?

```
$re = "/\\/specific-folder\\/*([0-9,a-z,A-Z,-]*)(.*)/"; 
$str = "http://www.domain.de/specific-folder/data/#link"; 
$subst = $1 // works, but i can't get rid of the original search string (?)
```

thanks a lot for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^.]*\.([^\/]*)\/.*?\/({.*?})\/(#.*)$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/44

```
$re = "/^[^.]*\\.([^\\/]*)\\/.*?\\/({.*?})\\/(#.*)$/m";
$str = "http://www.domain.de/specific-folder/{data}/#link";
$subst = "http://$2.$1/$3";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: this works perfect! thanks!!

is it possible to make the replacement in a text (globally?)

for e.g. this

`str = "<p>Text text <a class="a" href="http://www.domain.de/specific-folder/{data}/#link">Link</a> text text <a class="b" href="http://www.domain.de/specific-folder/{data}/#link">Link</a> text text</p>"`

into

`str = "<p>Text text <a class="a" href="http://{data}.domain.de/#link>Link</a> text text <a class="b" href="http://{data}.domain.de/#link">Link</a> text text</p>"`

Comment: thank you so much. i got a solution with your previous code in a callback in preg_replace, but this one is even better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(http://)www\.(domain\.de)/specific-folder/([^/]+)~', '$1$3$2', $str);
```